# How to access Bluemix application's runtime shell as root?

Tags: node.js, ssh, runtime, ibm-cloud

I have a Nodejs application running in Bluemix. I try to run a command to install dependencies in Nodejs application container. I accessed it using application's runtime SSH. I need root privileges to install dependencies. It is asking me password for sudo command. How can i get that password?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be installing dependencies this way.  The ssh terminal is intended for debugging purposes only:

> If you need to troubleshoot an instance of an app, you can gain SSH
>   access to the app using the SSH proxy and daemon.
>
> For example, one of your app instances may be unresponsive, or the log
>   output from the app may be inconsistent or incomplete. You can SSH
>   into the individual VM that runs the problem instance to troubleshoot.

Source: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/app-ssh-overview.html

NodeJS dependencies can be installed by adding a package.json file:

> Cloud Foundry expects a package.json in your Node.js app. You can
>   specify the version of Node.js you want to use in the engine node of
>   your package.json file.
>
> In general, Cloud Foundry supports the two most recent versions of
>   Node.js. See the GitHub Node.js buildpack page for current
>   information.

Source: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/node-tips.html

Comment: I am facing an issue. which is that my runtime environment is linux and i need libre  office in that environment which is not currently there. how can i specify that in package.json?

Comment: @MuhammadHamza You could try creating a custom buildpack - https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/custom.html